# java.lang.ClassCastException: while running web application in HEROKU

Tags: jsp, servlets, heroku, classcastexception

Iam trying to run a web application in heroku. 
Its a simple web application with JSP-Servlet architecture.

http://electric-rain-8409.herokuapp.com/client/home?page=Page&name=maginfoINSERT&type=form
when I hit this URL it gives this error

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

```
*at org.apache.jsp.client.Page_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.client.Page_jsp:185)
-----
-----
-----
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:288)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:115)
at com.akas.magclub.servlet.UrlForward.doGet(UrlForward.java:34)*
```

The servlet it tries to hit is UrlForward which just forwrds the request to a jsp page identified by parameter Page.

The amazing thing is that the following url works
http://electric-rain-8409.herokuapp.com/client/home?page=frontpage&tag=

Can't really understand why this is happening.The whole web application works fine in local machine environment.

Comment: What JSP code has generated line 185 of `org.apache.jsp.client.Page_jsp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error. The JSP page where the servlet forwards this request to tries to get the parameter map and it tries to do it like this

```
HashMap <String,String[]> parammap=(HashMap<String,String[]>)request.getParameterMap();
```

but request.getParameterMap() returns an unmodifiableCollection which cannot be cast to HashMap simply because it is read only and HashMap provides R/W access.

So changing it to

```
Map<String,String[]> parammap=request.getParameterMap();
```

solved the problem.

But one thing still remains. The above code with HashMap works well in locally when running in tomcat but fails when running in heroku.